# I'm looking to get the button (currently centered) to animate to the top left onClick, I already have a function connected to this element

Tags: javascript

I want a button positioned in the center to animate to either the top of the page or the top left. I already have one function connected to this element that removes a solid black page and enters the main site. Is it possible to have this element run two functions; one being the translate animation and two being the removal of a solid background color.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sean Marc Howe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div id="intro"; class="intro"></div>
    <div id="buttonWrapper1" class="buttonWrapper"><button class="introBtn" onclick="javascript:one(); two();"><img></button></div>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>




.intro {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.buttonWrapper {
  z-index: 10;
}
.buttonWrapper:active {
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.introBtn {
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  top: 40%;
  right: 645px;
  left: 645px;
  z-index: 5;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 7px;
}
/* .introBtn:active {
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
} */

.introBtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 7px;
  z-index: 2;
}

body {
  background-image: url("/images/pexels-kevin-ku-577585.jpg");
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@keyframes slide {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0px, -280px);
  }
}


var bool = true;
function one() { 
    
    (bool) ? document.getElementById("intro").style.background = "rgb(0, 0, 0)" :  document.getElementById("intro").style.background = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
    bool = !bool;

// // function two(){
//     document.getElementById('intro').className ='classname';
//   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible you could use javascript as you did before to add a css class and then have it change using `transition`. Then your css will figure out what to do for you, and animate your object.

I'm using [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) in my example but you can use `add` and `remove` if you only want it to fire once, and not be toggleable.

```js
var bool = true;

function fadeOut() {
    document.getElementById("intro").classList.toggle("active");
}

function moveButton() {
    document.getElementById("buttonWrapper1").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.intro {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 2s ease;
}
.intro.active {
  background: black;
}

.buttonWrapper {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /* Set transition to animate */
  transition: 3s ease;
}

.buttonWrapper.active {
  left: 10px;
}

.buttonWrapper.active .introBtn {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.introBtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  top: 40%;
  right: 645px;
  left: 645px;
  z-index: 5;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 7px;
}
.introBtn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div id="intro"; class="intro active"></div>
    <div id="buttonWrapper1" class="buttonWrapper"><button class="introBtn" onclick="javascript:fadeOut(); moveButton();"><img></button></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have been playing around with your suggestion but i can't seem to find how the button is animating.

What is the purpose of these:
.buttonWrapper.active {
  left: 10px;
}

.buttonWrapper.active .introBtn {
  border: 2px solid white;
}

I have got the button to the center, now i want it to go diagonally to the top left.

Comment: I have just figured it out. Is it possible for the new button position to become a new element with different functions e.g using that button to open a menu? Or is this too complicated. Many thanks for your help so far!

Comment: you can use some of the same code that i have made and just superimpose an element in the same container as you have the same button. Then you can show that on the click making the other element show up. If the answer helped you remember to accept it as the answer.

Comment: I have created another button which is superimposed, I've also styled it and created the js function but for some reason the block is doing nothing.


<div id="buttonWrapper1" class="buttonWrapper"><button class="introBtn"
            onclick="javascript:fadeOut(); moveButton();Visible();"><img src="/images/Power.on.white.png"></button></div>
    <div id="buttonWrapper2" class="buttonWrapper3"style="display: none;"><button class="introBtn1"
            ><img src="/images/Power.on.white.png"></form></button></div> -->

Comment: CSS
.buttonWrapper3 {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
}

JavaScript
function Visible() {
    var T = document.getElementById("buttonWrapper3");
    T.style.display = "display";  // <-- Set it to block
}

Comment: First: you javascript `var T = document.getElementById("buttonWrapper2");` you are looking for buttonWrapper3, but you need to look for buttonWrapper2, since you are getting `id` and not class.
I have set up a fiddle for you [try to look at this](https://jsfiddle.net/zeonfrost/6kbj8vry/14/)